# Has any science fiction been written that's set in the TRAPPIST-1 system?

Tags: history-of, inspiration

I have an idea about a story set in the [TRAPPIST-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRAPPIST-1) system. In particular, the main topic is about the three planets in the habitable zone. Now, I am not a writer, but I think I would really like to try and write this down. I love the idea (that, obviously, I cannot share here).

**Has anyone written anything about a TRAPPIST-1 setting yet?**

Comment: The first question is answerable - I have added an answer below.  The second question is broad, since it could describe almost any science fiction work.  I'd suggest removing the second question.

Comment: I was trying to ask something without revealing the original idea, I guess it can't be done. Thanks!

Comment: If you're worried about your work being too similar to other stories, I'd suggest asking the question on https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/.  It's a good place to get feedback on your ideas.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes - there are writings about Trappist-1**

According to [this article](http://mashable.com/2017/02/22/planets-trappist-1-short-stories-art/#LX.W8UkpYiqT), there is a website dedicated to Trappist-1.

You can find it [here](http://www.trappist.one/).

The website as scientific information about the system, as well as short stories, art, and even a graphic novel.

Some of the art is very good.

[image]

Comment: Oh no :( (just kidding, thank you!)